# Increasing value of float variable by 1 using batch script

Tags: batch-file

I need increase `float` variable `versionName` value every time I run batch script. *Like 2.5 to 2.6 ,2.7 so on*.

This is my file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="auto" package="com.sisapp.in.globalthesc" android:versionName="2.5" android:versionCode="8">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
    <supports-screens android:resizeable="true"  android:largeScreens="true"/>
    <application android:icon="@drawable/sisIconLaunch">        
        <receiver android:name=".DeviceBootReceiver" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I am trying like below but it is not working

```
@echo off
set "inputfile=D:\raja\SIS\SIS_Product\edTheSIS\AppIcons\Global\MenifestFile\AndroidManifest.xml
set /A versionName=%versionName%+1
```

Comment: is that the exact format of your `xml` file? the formatting seems off.

Comment: ok, you edited it, but I am refering to the spacing pre-text.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard - I am not sure if I understand. But this time I tried my best :) to give exact xml file.

Comment: seems better now.

Comment: This could be vastly easier in PowerShell: are you really stuck with cmd?

Comment: @Richard - More than 90% of work has been done using cmd. Seems different if using PowerShell for some specific work. I am planning to execute all steps using single run. Thank you.

Comment: You can still run the [tag:powershell] command(s) from a [tag:batch-file], so this shouldn't affect your workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so let me start of by saying that batch is not the best tool to manipulate `xml` files, there are tools that can do much better than batch.

Note also that this script is purely a hack, if the format of your `xml` file changes (especially the manifest tag line) from what you have posted, then it will not work and it *WILL* break your file. So before you start **make a backup of your `xml` file**.

Also, this explicitely replaces the numeric value it finds, if the value exists anywhere else in the file, it will also replace it.

Lastly and very importantly, if your `xml` file consists of any `!` characters, this will not cater for it and it will be excluded from the replace.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "inputfile=D:\raja\SIS\SIS_Product\edTheSIS\AppIcons\Global\MenifestFile\AndroidManifest.xml"

    for /f tokens^=8^delims^=^" %%i in ('type "%inputfile%" ^| findstr "android:versionName"') do set vers=%%i
    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=." %%i in ("!vers!") do (
         set decia=%%i
         set decib=%%j
         if "!decib!" lss "9" (
                set /a decib+=1
          ) else (
                set decib=0
                set /a decia+=1
        )
        set newver=!decia!.!decib!
    )
    for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('type "%inputfile%" ^| find /v /n "" ^& break ^> "%inputfile%"') do (
         set "str=%%a"
         call set "str=%%str:*]=%%"
         if "!str:~0,15!" == "<manifest xmlns" set "str=!str:%vers%=%newver%!"
         >>%inputfile% echo(!str!
  )
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Not working! all lines of Manifest file are replacing with `str!` character as well as getting error msg in cmd _The system cannot find file specified_. Why batch file dependent with tags of xml file.

Comment: Did you copy everything as is? are you combining it with more code in another script? Try this as is, on its own in a different script. I fixed the file not found issue, you can try it again.

Comment: @CGPA6.4: `if the format of your xml file changes (especially the manifest tag line) from what you have posted, then it will not work and it WILL break your file.`

Comment: @CGPA6.4 It is important that you understand that I built this based on your exact example. If your xml differs it will not work. I did one more update, please retry with updated code... your new file contains the `package` line, which you never showed in your example in the question.

Comment: I also updated your question to reflect the actual line as per your screenshot example.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard - Your code works fine. Only one issue seems here is if you see very first line of `xml` file, `8` is there if `versionName` also `8` then both are getting changed. Seems you are using loop in program is that required. Thank you.

Comment: Try it as is now please... if it does not work, please verify for me if there are whitespace before `<manifest`

Comment: @GerhardBarnard - Thank you so much. Its working perfect. Just last question not related to this question. If I want to change `versionCode` too every time by +1 (not float) how much effort I need.

Comment: exactly the same as we did above, you would need to repeat the lines 4 to 9 and specifically grab token 10 where we did `token^=8` then do the addition, no if statement needed as we are not dealing with decimals here.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard - I am facing issue while changing `versionCode`, If can I ask new question. Thank you.